# How to display tabs heading center aligned in angularjs material design

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am following this link for tabs in my webpage.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs

This is code for tabs.

```
<div ng-cloak>
  <md-content>
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>

      <md-tab label="one">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
            <p> Tab 2 contents</p>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>

      <md-tab label="two">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
            <p> Tab 2 contents</p>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>

      <md-tab label="three">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
            <p> Tab 3 contents</p>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

The above code displays tabs heading in left of HTML page

How to display tabs heading in center of HTML page?

I have one more requirement. There is a button in tab1 contents. on clicking of that button how to move to second tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can use Following link to align centre/left/bottom etc  the Heading/any elements

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment

Ex:-  `layout="row"  layout-align="center center"`

For making tabs  as Wizard

Controller Logic :-

```
$scope.max = 2; // max you can put your number 
  $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
  $scope.nextTab = function() {
    var index = ($scope.selectedIndex == $scope.max) ? 0 : $scope.selectedIndex + 1;
    $scope.selectedIndex = index;

  };
```

Html :-

```
   <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="" md-selected="selectedIndex" md-center-tabs="true">
      .....
   </md-tabs>
```

Plunker In Action :-

http://plnkr.co/edit/rOh0Yy?p=preview

Comment: Tabs are left aligned in plnkr link you provided

Comment: Updated the Plunker pls take a look tabs centered

Comment: for me it is still showing the tabs in left not centered.

Comment: NO i added  some code to make it center let me check and update the answer then

Comment: Pls take a look and let me know i updated in answer  added new plunker

Comment: You can use `md-center-tabs directive` as  @charitha-goonewardena pointed. Have a look at https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs . This functionality was added as part of the issue https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1992

Answer (score 8):

**md-center-tabs="true"** worked for me

```
<md-tabs md-center-tabs="true" md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom class="md-primary" style="border: none;">
```